# Unable to map points on a map drawn using shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, latitude-longitude, mapping

I am new to this area. I have a dataset with latitude longitude data of the city of London. I would like to draw the corresponding map of the city with this points superimposed onto it. I am using python for the visualization. The shapefile I downloaded is from here:https://data.gov.uk/dataset/6cdebf5d-c69b-4480-8c9c-53ab8a816b9d/statistical-gis-boundary-files-for-london . But when I produced the maps, I noticed the there is a huge difference between the lat/lon values I have and the map generated by the shapefile. Below are the figures generated:

[image]

Below is the lat/lon values I have.

[image]

It seems to me that there must be some scaling that needs to be done to put the red points on top of the map. But I have no idea how or why or if something else is wrong.

Being a complete newbie in working with lat/lon values, I am probably making a very rookie mistake. Below is also the Python code I am using:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point, Polygon
crs = {'init':'epsg:4326'}

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['lon'],df['lat'])]

state_map = gpd.read_file('../statistical-gis-boundaries-
    london/ESRI/MSOA_2004_London_High_Resolution.shp')

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs = crs, geometry = geometry)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(12,10))
state_map.plot(ax=ax)
geo_df.plot(ax=ax,markersize=20,color='red',alpha=0.4)
```

Comment: The coordinates shown on the X/Y axes of your first figure are NOT latitude/longitude.  They look like UTM coordinates.  You need to determine what the coordinate system is for each of the two datasets, and then convert the coordinates of one of the datasets to the same coordinate system as used in the other dataset.  Note that latitude/longitude are a "geographic coordinate system", and most other coordinate systems such as UTM are "projected coordinate systems".  This is the `crs` in your code.

Comment: The datasets are in different coordinate systems. You need to tell us the content of the `.prj` file associated with each.

Comment: @SonofaBeach Not UTM (northing values aren't big enough) but more likely British National Grid (EPSG:27700).

Comment: In your second picture, it's more usual to map the latitude values (5x) against the y (vertical) axis and the longitude values against the x (horizontal) axis. You'll need to convert one or the other to same coordinate reference system.

Comment: and your lat-lon plot is the wrong way round - London is around 0 longitude (at Greenwich) and around 51 N latitude

Comment: https://epsg.io/27700 as others have mentioned. not sure what your other point data is from - one of the datasets needs re-projecting

Comment: @mkennedy; yes indeed, the state_map.crs yields `epsg:27700`

Comment: this might be useful http://geopandas.org/projections.html